# How to get details from LinkedIn in java-script?

Tags: javascript, fetch, linkedin-api

I am creating one application in java-script which fetch information form LinkedIn which we need.
My problem is that...  I need company name, Experience, city, country from LinkedIn profile.
I'll try but i am only able to fetch name, surname, industry and headline.
Here is my code which fetch above details.

```
function loadData() {
IN.API.Profile("me")
.fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl","headline","industry"])
.params({"company-name": "Adobe", "sortCriteria" : "R", "current-company": "true"})
.result(function(result) {
  profile = result.values[0];
  profHTML = "<p><a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
  profHTML += "<img class=img_border align=\"left\" src=\"" + profile.pictureUrl + "\"></a>";      
  profHTML += "<a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
  profHTML += "<h2 class=myname>" + profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName + "</a> </h2>";
  profHTML += "<span class=myheadline>" + profile.headline + "</span>";
  profHTML += "<h3>" + profile.industry + "</h3>";

  $("#profiles").html(profHTML);
});
```

But i need to fetch company name,  location and experience. i try lot of tag but didn't success.
Please give me any hint or direct me where i need which tag.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are there no api docs you can reference? Maybe this will help > http://developer.linkedin.com/apis#companies

Comment: Check the profile api documentation https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api. It looks like there is a position list with a company attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing your code above, you'd have something like:

```
function loadData() {
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .fields(["id","firstName","lastName","pictureUrl","headline","industry","threeCurrentPositions"])
    .params({"company-name": "Adobe", "sortCriteria" : "R", "current-company": "true"})
    .result(function(result) {
      profile = result.values[0];
      positions = profile.threeCurrentPositions;

      // call to company api to get company-specific location data?
    });
}
```

Just parse out the returned JSON data from the `threeCurrentPositions` as needed to get the position data, which includes the company name and company id. The company id can be used to pull company location data from the [Company API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields), if you need that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
       function onLinkedInLogin() {
            IN.API.Profile("me")
            .fields(["id", "firstName", "lastName", "pictureUrl", "publicProfileUrl", "industry", "location", "headline"])
            .result(function (result) {
                var firstName = result.values[0].firstName;
                var lastName = result.values[0].lastName;
                IN.parse(document.getElementById("profile"))
            })
         }
```